# Insert records if criteria is met Room Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a situation in which I want to compare list of records fetched from server with local DB records and if certain criteria is met then insert the records in Database. e.g. I have `Entity` column named `mediaUploadedCount`. `mediaUploadedCount` is `29` in local DB. I hit API to fetch new records and if this record's `mediaUploadedCount` is `28` then ignore this record while insertion. One possible solution for this record might be:

- Fetch records from DB
- Compare server records with local DB records
- Insert all those records for which criteria is met

But this approach will slow down the insertion process.

> Is there any way in which we can apply certain criteria before insertion or any other thought for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

I see two scenarios here:

1. You treat `mediaUploadedCount` as your **primary uid** and Room handles non-duplication for you.
2. You insert with a query condition in your Room Dao:

```
    INSERT INTO table-name (column-names) 
    WHERE condition
```

Comment: In this query, I want to compare record with db column value. say i have to insert 50 records and for all fifty records, I want to compare `mediaUploadedCount` with value of `mediaUploadedCount` in DB.

Comment: for scenario `You treat mediaUploadedCount as your primary uid and Room handles non-duplication for you.

`, this will not work. as 28 is different from 29 but I want to ignore 28 and retain 29 as 29 ios the latest recrod.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to store this upload count as a variable? Can you not achieve the same thing by getting the size of media returned when you get them?

Comment: I have a `Recyclerview` in which I am should `29/130` i.e. `mediaUploadedCount = 29` and `medialTotalCount = 130`, for this purpose separate counts needs to be maintained. If everytime, I need to calculate from sdcard files , it will be slower to render this in `onBindViewHolder`